# Which plugin do I need to use in Angular 2 to show date

Tags: angular2-template

On clicking on next and prev button date should change as shown here:

[image: Requirement]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For such functional I use moment.js with next code:

Template:

```
<div class="month">
    <i class="fa fa-angle-left fa-2x" aria-hidden="true" (click)="prevMonth()"></i>
    <span>{{month}}</span>
    <i class="fa fa-angle-right fa-2x" aria-hidden="true" (click)="nextMonth()"></i>
  </div>
```

Component.ts:

```
    date: Date = new Date();
    month = moment().format('MMMM');
    dateNow = moment();


    prevMonth() {
      this.month = moment(this.dateNow).subtract(1, 'months').format('MMMM');
      this.dateNow.subtract(1, 'months');
    }

    nextMonth() {
      this.month = moment(this.dateNow).add(1, 'months').format('MMMM');
      this.dateNow.add(1, 'months');
    }
```